# Static блок инициализации

Tags: java

Можно привести пример, когда static блок инициализации отрабатывает 2 раза?

Comment: Вроде не должно такого быть. Это реальная проблема или вопрос на собеседовании?

Comment: При инициализации класса только, т. е. один раз для каждого экземпляра

Comment: Слышал о том, что static блок отрабатывает столько раз сколько класс загружается classloader-ом. Вот и возник вопрос, можно ли смоделировать данную ситуацию?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы правильно слышали, что блок статической инициализации отрабатывает столько раз, сколько класс загружается classloader-ом. Но так как classloader не будет дважды загружать класс, единственный способ добиться повторного вызова блока статической инициализации - это использовать второй classloader:

**SomeClass.java**

```
package com.example;

public class SomeClass {
    static {
        System.out.println("Static initialization");
    }
}
```

Компилируем и упаковываем

```
> javac -d test SomeClass.java
> jar cf test.jar -C test .
```

**Main.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws MalformedURLException {
        String pathToJar = "file:////D:/playground/java/test.jar";
        String className = "com.example.SomeClass";

        URL url = new URL(pathToJar);
        try (URLClassLoader cl1 = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { url });
             URLClassLoader cl2 = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { url })) {

            Class<?> c1 = cl1.loadClass(className);
            Class<?> c2 = cl2.loadClass(className);

            c1.newInstance();
            c2.newInstance();
        }
        catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | ClassNotFoundException exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Компилируем и запускаем

```
> javac Main.java
> java Main
```

Вывод, как и ожидалось

```
Static initialization
Static initialization
```

Comment: Технически это не запуск static блока для одного экземпляра несколько раз, это несколько экземпляров с одним static

Comment: И добавьте вывод сразу, пожалуйста, чтобы не приходилось додумывать или тестировать вручную.

Comment: @mikewoe насколько мне известно, это единственный способ.

Comment: Именно это было и нужно, огромное спасибо